# Copy Excel sheet to another excel book but just formats and values

Tags: vba, excel

I have two excel workbooks **Book_A** and **Book_B** and I know how to copy an entire sheet from **A -> B** with:

```
        wksSh1.Copy Before:=wkbBook_B.Sheets(1)
```

But I just want to copy the sheet with values and formats and not formulas. It is posible

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
wksSh1.Copy Before:=wkbBook_B.Sheets(1)
with wkbBook_B.Sheets(1).UsedRange
    .value = .value 'converts formulas to values
end with
```

Comment: @Jonathan Raul Tapia Lopez  - what do you mean by "directly" ?

Comment: Hey Tim, thanks for your response I mean with wksSh1.copyValues or something and Your response works for my.

Answer (score 4):

Use `PasteSpecial`:

```
wksSh1.Copy
With wkbBook_B.Sheets(1)
    .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End With
```

As Scott commented, for earlier versions of Excel (2003 +), you can use `xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats`.

Comment: `xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats`

Comment: But I am more interested with **wksSh1.Copy Before:=wkbBook_B.Sheets(1)** because also copy the sheet's name

Answer (score 0):

If you know the number of rows and columns (or you can use a row and a column always valued to calculate them) this is safer:

```
For i = 2 To numberOfRows
   For j = 1 To numberOfColumns
      Cells(i, j).Value = Cells(i, j).Value
   Next
Next
```