# Creating a new tab

Tags: excel, vba

How to I add to this VBA code so it is only copying values and formats

```
Private Sub GENERATE_OP_SHEET_Click()
    Dim i As Byte
    For i = 1 To 1
        Sheets("TEMPLATE").Copy After:=Sheets("TEMPLATE")
        Set Sh = ActiveSheet
        ActiveSheet.Name = Range("g2").Text
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: You can essentially find your answer here https://stackoverflow.com/q/14881032/2727437

Comment: get rid of `For i = 1 To 1` and `Next` statements since you'd loop once (hence no loop) and you don't use `i` anywhere

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copy Excel sheet to another excel book but just formats and values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14881032/copy-excel-sheet-to-another-excel-book-but-just-formats-and-values)

Answer (score 0):

you could try this:

```
Private Sub GENERATE_OP_SHEET_Click()
    Sheets("TEMPLATE").Copy After:=Sheets("TEMPLATE")
    With ActiveSheet ' after 'Copy' statemement the copied sheet is the "active" one
        .Name = Range("g2").Text
        .UsedRange.Value = .UsedRange.Value ' leave values only
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @OliverCrawford, any feedback?

Answer (score 0):

Based on my test, please try the code as below:

```
Private Sub GENERATE_OP_SHEET_Click()
    Sheets("TEMPLATE").Copy After:=Sheets("TEMPLATE")
    ActiveSheet.Name = Range("g2").Text
    With Sheets("TEMPLATE").UsedRange
        .Value = .Value 'converts formulas to values
    End With
End Sub
```

For more information, please see:

[Copy Excel sheet to another excel book but just formats and values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14881032/copy-excel-sheet-to-another-excel-book-but-just-formats-and-values)

Comment: Won't that change the source TEMPLATE sheet to values?  The OP wants the destination sheet to be converted to values